# How to escape additional empty line while parsing pairwise data in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have an input file that looks like this:

```
>Seq_1;1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>Seq_2;1
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

And there are many more pairwise line like that.
What I want to do is to simply print it out like this:

```
>Seq_1;1 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>Seq_2;1 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

But why this code fail:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

   while ( <> ) {
        chomp;
        my $line = $_;
        my $rdn = "";
        my $sq  = "";

        if ( $line =~ /^>/ ) {
            $rdn = $line;
        }
        elsif ($line =~ /^[ATCG]/) {
            $sq = $line;
        }

         print "$rdn $sq\n";

    }
```

It print this instead:

```
>Seq_1;1
 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>Seq_2;1
 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question; but you may find it helpful: `xargs -n 2 < file.fa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is 'pairwise', and unless you want to explicitly check each line for the patterns you describe, why not just read two lines at a time? Then do your processing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


while (my $line1 = <>) {
    my $line2 = <>;

    chomp $line1;
    chomp $line2;

#   ...do_something...

    print "$line1 $line2\n";
}
```

Results:

```
>Seq_1;1 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>Seq_2;1 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk could make it:

```
$ awk '/^>/ {getline a; print $0,a}' file
```

it loads in the variable `a` the next line of the ones starting with `>`. Then prints both together.

#### Test

```
$ cat file
>Seq_1;1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>Seq_2;1
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
$ awk '/^>/ {getline a; print $0,a}' file
>Seq_1;1 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>Seq_2;1 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: Use `getline()` [only when necessary](http://awk.info/?tip/getline). It's not necessary here. There are safer/better ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you, @SuicidalSteve! I will take a look at it later on and try to update my answer with a safer method.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're reading the file line by line and printing on every line?
You probably want something more like this. Storing the value of the first line in the first iteration, then printing it out on the second interation. Note this code is by no means the best, as if your file isn't exactly like you've posted above it will almost certainly print the incorrect thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

   my $rdn = "";

   while ( <> ) {
        chomp;
        my $line = $_;    
        if ( $line =~ /^>/ ) {
            $rdn = $line;
            next;
        }
        elsif ($line =~ /^[ATCG]/) {
            my $sq = $line;
            print "$rdn $sq\n";
        }    
    }
```

Comment: The `next` in the then-part of the `if` is not needed as the only other code in the loop is an `elsif` clause. Alternatively, keep the `next` and change the `elsif` to an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, you set either `$rdn` or `$sq`, never both.  Then you print both of them (one of them always "") with a `\n` at the end.

Try this, the idea being to only chomp off the `\n` if it's an even-numbered line, in that case printing a space instead:

```
my $lineno = 0;
while (<>) {
   if ($lineno % 2 == 0) {
      chomp;
      print $_, " ";
   } else {
      print;
   }
   $lineno++;
}
```